# error - "attempt to write a readonly database\r\nattempt to write a readonly database"

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, connection-string

I am using a SQLite database in a WPF windows application. After installing the windows application the database inside this folder like this:

```
static SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Program Files (x86)\hedronix\qScan\test.s3db;");
```

But when I am trying to access the database from this location of the windows application showing this error.

1. How can I solve that?
2. In this situation, how can I set default connection string for accessing SQLite database after install this application on any local computer?

Comment: By giving the user permission to that file. Usually there should be no writable files in the application folders and by default no write permissions are given.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, By the way, how can I write SQLite connectionstring for establishing connection?